# Unable to use existing shared key vault in different resource group in azure bicep

Tags: azure-bicep

Iam using code like below.

resource kv 'Microsoft. Keyvault/Vaults@2022-06-01' existing = {
name : keyvaultName
Scope : resource(keyvault resource group Name).

But it's searching keyvault in target resource group. Any suggestions to fix this issue

Need to retrieve key vault indifferent resource group from default resource group/ target scope.

Comment: scope should be `scope: resourceGroup('<resource group name>')` or `scope: resourceGroup('subscription Id>', '<resource group name>')` if you wanna get a reference for a KV in a different resource group / subscription

Comment: Hello, I tried above thing. But it's fetching  existing keyvault in new resource group & unable to find. Throwing error

Comment: does your account have access tot he KV ? could you share the rror with us please ?